# Post type with option to select users in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I created a new post type namely  interview  in my wordpress site.  Its slug is  interview . And I have some users and their  roles  are  interviewers .When i add a new interview then i need to assign this interview to interviewer.

I  need  to  set  an  additional  field  in  my  interview  post , that  has  an  option  to  select  one  or  more  interviewer  ( Here  interviewer  are  registered  users  with  the  role  of  interviewer ) .

How can i do that . Please help.I am searching this for some time .But i din't get Correct way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a option call Custom Feilds on Screen options

[image]

Comment: Really thanks for your reply.But custom field option is only for pages of wordpress not for post .I can add custom field for post using types.But here my need to select an existing user or users with role of interviewer  for to assign interview.

Comment: Who said it is there for posts also.. I am using Version 3.9.2, what is your version

Comment: Sorry Custom field for post type also.Thanks.But here my need to select an existing user or users with role of interviewer for to assign interview.How to list users as select or drop down in that post.

Comment: Sorry Brother, I think for that kind of requirement you should have external plugin to search or develop

Comment: Really thanks brother.I forgot the case of custom field in the post type.You help to remember that point.Anyway i am going to search any plugin is available for to do this .

Comment: advanced-custom-fields  plugin help to do this.It Works.Thanks allot.

Answer (score 1):

To assign user to custom post types, 1st you needs to add author support in custom post type. you can ad this simply by adding

```
'supports'            => array( 'title','editor','author'),
```

"author" filed in your post type arguments. once you add it, you can see that each post author is available as a meta filed in post.

Then you needs to add following filter to overwrite the WordPress default author to your custom post type and your custom user-role.

```
    add_filter('wp_dropdown_users', 'test');
function test($output) 
{
    global $post;

    //Doing it only for the custom post type
    if($post->post_type == ('your-post-type-slug'))
    {
        $users = get_users(array('role'=>'your-custom-role'));
       $output .= "<p>Assign this post to</p> <select id='post_author_override' name='post_author_override' class=''>";
    foreach($users as $user)
    {
        $output .= "<option value='".$user->id."'>".$user->user_login."</option>";
    }
    $output .= "</select>";
 }
 return $output;
}
```

Then you can assign user to your custom post types.

Comment: Thanks.I try this code but i cant see any users list in "Assign this post to"  dropdown & what happen when i select a user?,is that save in post meta field? can i make it as a multiple select option? . I think your code is good ,if you modify this it become more good .

Comment: Once you add author supports to your custom post it will show the author meta-box. so first you have to add 'author' supports in your custom post types.Then to assign the your custom post to each users, you can do it by changing author.